# Android Drag and Drop Button Relative Layout

Tags: android

I am building an app that uses buttons to display text and then at some point the same button will display an image.

The buttons are programmatically created and have varying sizes and positions.
I have used Relative Layout for the buttons.

I need to make it possible to drag and drop the buttons.
I found a you tube tutorial that shows you how to make a textview that you can drag and drop. I have done the first part and can get it to drag. I have also made it work for a button.

When I add this code to my app-with the buttons made in relative Layout it does not work-the app crashes.

Below is my code and I have marked the line that makes the app crash.

```
package com.example.button;

import com.example.dragproject.MainActivity.DragShadow;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout layout;
    Button newButton;
    Button buttonByXml;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonByXml = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RL);
        buttonByXml.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    button(500,300, (float) 230.2,(float) 230.2, 1, "untitled");
    button(200,400, (float) 430.2,(float) 630.2, 2, "untitled1");   

    button(250,150, (float) 130.2,(float) 730.2, 3, "untitled2");
    button(250,150, (float) 330.2,(float) 30.2, 3);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void button(int x, int y, float xx, float yy, int devno, String img) {

        String a = Integer.toString(devno);

        newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setOnLongClickListener((OnLongClickListener) this);//PROBLEM
        layout.addView(newButton);
        newButton.setX((float) xx);
        newButton.setY((float) yy);
        newButton.getLayoutParams().width = x;
        newButton.getLayoutParams().height = y;

        String mDrawableName = img;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());

        newButton.setBackgroundResource(resID);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void button(int x, int y, float xx, float yy, int devno) {

        String a = Integer.toString(devno);

        newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setOnLongClickListener((OnLongClickListener) this);//PROBLEM
        layout.addView(newButton);
        newButton.setX((float) xx);
        newButton.setY((float) yy);
        newButton.getLayoutParams().width = x;
        newButton.getLayoutParams().height = y;

        newButton.setText(a);

    }


    OnLongClickListener Click = new OnLongClickListener(){

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            DragShadow dragshadow = new DragShadow(v);
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            v.startDrag(data, dragshadow, v, 0);
            return false;

        }


    };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private class DragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder{

        ColorDrawable greyBox;

        public DragShadow(View view){
            super(view);
            greyBox = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas){
            greyBox.draw(canvas);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint){

            View v = getView();
            int height = (int)v.getHeight();
            int width = (int)v.getWidth();
            greyBox.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
            shadowSize.set(width, height);
            shadowTouchPoint.set((int)width/2, (int)height/2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the log cat:

```
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928): Process: com.example.button, PID: 19928
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.button/com.example.button.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.button.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnLongClickListener
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.button.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnLongClickListener
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.example.button.MainActivity.button(MainActivity.java:57)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.example.button.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-19 09:06:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the logcat error.

Comment: I have added it to the main post

Answer (score 0):

```
  newButton.setOnLongClickListener((OnLongClickListener) this);//PROBLEM
```

`this` is your Activity and not an `OnLongClickListener`, the cast fails. It would work (even without the cast) if your MainActivity did `implements onLongClickListener`.

You initialize a onLongClickListener here:

```
 OnLongClickListener Click = new OnLongClickListener(){

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        DragShadow dragshadow = new DragShadow(v);
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        v.startDrag(data, dragshadow, v, 0);
        return false;

    }


};
```

So use it with:

```
 newButton.setOnLongClickListener(Click);
```

For style's sake you should move the initialization somewhere else (begin of the class, not right in the middle between methods) and use a lower case name.

Comment: Can you give me any advice on how to make it drop where I leave it, at the moment it only picks it up, and when I let go it goes back to its original location

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that.